# Coding Graphics and KeyListener in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, keylistener

I was wondering how to properly use the Graphics library and also the Keylistener in JAVA. Underneath is my code, i believe i have done something wrong because the Window is blank with no Oval. Please help me out!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int x=100,y=100;

    boolean u,d,r,l;

    public <addKeyListener> void run(){
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        setSize(800,800);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.run(); 
        }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(x,y,40,40);
    repaint();
    }
    {


    if(u =true){
    y-=200;

    } 
    if(d = true){
    y+=2;
    }
    if(r = true){
        x-=2;
        }
    if(l = true){
        x+=2;}
    }








    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    char code = e.getKeyChar();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            u = true;}
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                l = true;}
                if(code == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                    d = true;}
                    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                        r = true;}

    }



    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        char code = e.getKeyChar();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            u = false;}
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                l = false;}
                if(code == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                    d = false;}
                    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                        r = false;}

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you made a mistake when copy and pasting your code.  Underneath your `paint` function, there's a code block without a preceding function definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're drawing directly in the JFrame, something that is dangerous to do (as you're finding out).
2. You're not calling the super's `paint(...)` method from within your paint override preventing the JFrame doing the painting that it itself needs to be doing.
3. You're calling `repaint()` from within a painting method -- never do this.
4. You've not read the painting in Swing tutorial yet.

Instead:

1. Draw in a JPanel's paintComponent method.
2. Call the super's paintComponent inside your override.
3. Use Key Bindings not KeyListeners (Google for the tutorial as it will explain how to use these).

---

Check the [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) link for links to tutorials and resources.

For example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleAnimationEg extends JPanel {
   private static final int OVAL_WIDTH = 20;
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private int x = 0;
   private int y = 0;

   public SimpleAnimationEg() {
      addKeyBindings();
   }

   private void addKeyBindings() {
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

      KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0);
      inputMap.put(keyStroke, keyStroke.toString());
      actionMap.put(keyStroke.toString(), new MyAction(0, -1));

      keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0);
      inputMap.put(keyStroke, keyStroke.toString());
      actionMap.put(keyStroke.toString(), new MyAction(0, 1));

      keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0);
      inputMap.put(keyStroke, keyStroke.toString());
      actionMap.put(keyStroke.toString(), new MyAction(-1, 0));

      keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0);
      inputMap.put(keyStroke, keyStroke.toString());
      actionMap.put(keyStroke.toString(), new MyAction(1, 0));
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.fillOval(x, y, OVAL_WIDTH, OVAL_WIDTH);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
      private int xDirection;
      private int yDirection;

      public MyAction(int xDirection, int yDirection) {
         this.xDirection = xDirection;
         this.yDirection = yDirection;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         x += xDirection;
         y += yDirection;
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleAnimationEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleAnimationEg());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: @JayeshKhullar: [check link for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12545773/522444)