# Java Swing - How do I add an appearing effect for JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, animation, jlabel

I have to create a menu bar with a logo panel at far end of the bar and I have done it. But It's required that logo must have "appearing" effect? How can I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by appearing effect? An animation on start of the program (e.g. the label flying in), hover/mouseover effect or something completely different?

Comment: yeah, label has the effect. It's something like effects in MS powerpoint(fly in, float in... )... Can you help me please?

Comment: Does java swing support this?

Comment: Please tell us which of the effects the desired effect is, so we can provide more specific help. Generally, you could use a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the animation.

Comment: I need a simple example to understand it, so you can help me using any effect that you think it's easy to understand xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with "appearring effect", but if you want to create some color effects, you could extend the `JLabel` class and add some custom Color/Image Effects. Maybe this example for creating a [JLabel with various effects](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing/JLabel/JLabel_with_various_effects_in_Java.htm) gets you started.

See also [How to animate a JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545744/java-animate-jlabel)