# Is it possible to position a JLabel using a decimal number such as double?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am making a platformer game using Java. I have a character in the form of a JLable with an Image Icon that can be moved around using the arrow keys. I am using the setBounds() method to set the position of the JLabel, but this method only takes int values as x and y arguments, and I would like more precise control. Using a null layout, is it possible to use more precise values such as double to position a JLabel?

Thank you for your time, and have a great day.

Comment: Think about it. Can you have a half pixel or a 3/4 pixel? (the answer is no)

Answer (score 4):

Well if you are using `JLabels` then you are using Swing, and Swing has non-floating point coordinates system, so no you cannot.

Answer (score 2):

[Looking at the JavaDocs for `JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)...

[`setLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation(int,%20int)) takes `ints` as parameters. There doesn't seem to be a way to use decimal coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX can do. However in Swing the coordinates are integer pixels.

You could draw scaled 2x2 in memory (Image getGraphics) and then rescale to achieve half int steps of 0.5; but that would blur (interpolated pixels) or flicker (best nearby match).

For *zooming* scalable vector graphics, .vg, using the **batik** library would be feasible.

For text *subpixel hinting* can on some LED screens position black text on thirds of a pixel, depending on the layout of the Red, Green and Blue subpixels.

> In general it is not worth the effort to attempt the above. Except that **JavaFX** has nice animation support, CSS styling and animation effects.

Answer (score 1):

As others are saying, UI components are designed to position only with exact pixel coordinates.

You could store a location in `double` and then round it to `int` when you actually set the location. Something like this:

```
double velX = ..., velY = ...;
double x    = ..., y    = ...;

void example() {
    int t = 1000 / 30;
    new Timer(t, (ActionEvent e) -> {
        x += t * velX;
        y += t * velY;
        label.setLocation((int) Math.round(x),
                          (int) Math.round(y));
    }).start();
}
```

That way you can move in smaller increments. It just won't be visible.

[There is a really great example of animating an image here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12545773/2891664) in a way very similar to what you're describing which you should take a look at. Trying to position components is really more trouble than it's worth, in my opinion, especially if you're trying to make something like a game. Performing custom painting is more flexible. (The tutorial is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).)